# Django. How to create django_easyselect_form with custom fieldset?

Tags: django

There is my model:

```
class MoneyTransfer(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, related_name='outcome_transfers')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, related_name='income_transfers')
    when = models.DateTimeField()
    total = models.FloatField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = TransferQuerySet.as_manager()
```

form:

```
SendTransferForm = select2_modelform(MoneyTransfer)
```

I have two usages of form:

```
1. fields = 'receiver', 'comment', 'total'
2. fields = 'sender', 'receiver', 'comment', 'total'
```

How to implement it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided not to use model form and created simple form with necessary widgets:

```
class SendTransferForm(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=BankAccount.objects.all(), widget=Select2(), label="Счёт отправителя")
    receiver = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=BankAccount.objects.all(), widget=Select2(), label="Счёт получателя")
    total = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'select2fake'}), label="Сумма")
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'select2fake'}), label="Комментарий")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two forms class

```
class FirstForm(ModelForm):
    class META:
        model = models.MoneyTransfer
        fields = ['receiver', 'comment', 'total']
```

and then:

```
class SecondForm(ModelForm):
    class META:
        model = models.MoneyTransfer
        fields = ['sender', 'receiver', 'comment', 'total']
```

Comment: it's okay, but I use django_easyselect package and need a solution for it